# Border on hover

Tags: css, sass

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npvmgvsu/1/)

I have a nav at the bottom of the screen, on hover, a sub menu pops up. I have this all working on the fiddle. The issue is with the border, the pop up menus border is 1px smaller and I want it to be inline with it's parents red border. How can I do this?

```
<div id="filter">
<ul>
<li class="small-2 columns">
    Color
    <ul>
        <li>
            Blue
        </li>
        <li>
            Green
        </li>
        <li>
            Yellow
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="small-2 columns end">
    Letter
    <ul>
        <li>
            A
        </li>
        <li>
            B
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: How do you have this much rep and you haven't learned by now that your question needs to contain *all relevant code*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify **left** and **right** properties on your `<ul>` (sub menu). You must remove `width: 100%;`

Like so:

```
#filter >ul >li >ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `calc` for the width of the menu pop-up to make it 2px wider. Then, move it to the left by -1px. See the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uqk1h1c1/

And the code :

```
#filter >ul >li >ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: -1px;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```